# Is there a way to remove all entries in a hash with a key greater than a certain number using the console alone?

Tags: redis

I'm making tests (automated and manual) for a system that uses Redis. Our API has no way to remove entries yet and that feature is a far way down the pipeline(I have no say in that). The only way we can remove entries from a particular hash is to use the HDEL command in the console.

Is there a way to delete all entries in a hash where the key fits a certain parameter through the console, like greater than a number? (I've just started working with Redis the other week, so I'm not fluent in everything the system has to offer yet, so sorry if it's actually super simple)

We're using a lot of custom systems along with Redis, so I'm not able to use something like a ruby or python script to do this.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You should write what you have done to try solving the question by yourself

Comment: Did you consider using RediSearch.io?